# How can I prove $\operatorname{Cl}(A) = \operatorname{Cl}(A-\{x\})$

Tags: general-topology

$A$ is a subset of topological space $X$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

How can I prove $\operatorname{Cl}(A) = \operatorname{Cl}(A-\{x\})$?

I was trying to prove it by two steps.

$\operatorname{Cl}(A) \subset \operatorname{Cl}(A-\{x\})$ and the opposite.

I got stuck with the former one....

Comment: Unless you have a typo, you’ve done the hard part: with any of the usual equivalent definitions of the closure of a set it’s almost immediate that if $B\subseteq A$, then $\operatorname{cl}B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$. What *is* your definition of $\operatorname{cl}A$?

Comment: Oh right... Thanks for letting me know. It was a typo and I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A-\{x\} \subseteq A$ so always $\operatorname{Cl}(A-\{x\}) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A)$.

And so for the reverse inclusion we only need that $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(A-\{x\})$ , as $\operatorname{Cl}(A) = \operatorname{Cl}(A - \{x\}) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(\{x\})$ (the second term is then a subset of the first). And this follows directly from the definition of $x$ being a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A limit point by definition is a point x such that:

$x\in cl(A)\setminus A^{°} \Rightarrow x\notin A^{°}$

And therefore $A^{°} \subset A\setminus \{ x\} $ indeed $A^{°} \subset A$ and $x\notin A^{°}$

also we know that $cl(A^{°})=cl(A)$

And therefore $cl(A\setminus \{ x\} ) \subset cl(A^{°} )=cl(A)$

The other direction is obvious